# Setting the parameters of a SP from a table row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am creating a stored procedure that will take in one parameter: @CommonImportID

This ID will be the PK of the CommonImport table. I need to use the row that this PK corresponds to, to assign each value in each column to its own variable, i.e. @uploadedBy = (value in uploadedBy column) etc etc. How would I write this statement

If you need any more info just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood your question correctly, something like this...

```
declare @uploadedBy varchar(50)
declare @anothervariable whatevertype 

select @uploadedBy=uploadedBy, 
       @anothervariable=anotherColumn 
from CommonImport 
where CommonImportID=@CommonImportID
```

Comment: Didn't realise it was so easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Nearly had it yourself

Declare @UploadedBy VarChar(64)
Declare @UploadedDate DateTime
Select @UploadedBy = UploadedBy, @UploadedDate = UploadedDate 
From CommonImportTable Where CommonImportID = @CommonImportID

for example